# Не работает загрузка коллекций DTO в Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee, orm, dto

Есть `Entity` с 4-мя `@OneToMany` отношениями:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "userInfo")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "getCommonUser", query = "select new ru.projects.prog_ja.dto.CommonUserTransfer( " +
                " u.userId, u.firstName, i.imageL, u.rating, u.lastName, u.createDate, u.birthDate, u.userQuestions, u.userPostsComments , u.userPosts, u.answers " +
                " ) " +
                " from UserInfo as u " +
                " join  u.userImage as i " +
                " where u.userId = :id"),
       
})
public class UserInfo {

    public static final String GET_COMMON_USER = "getCommonUser";

    private long userId;
    private String email;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private long rating;
    private Date createDate;
    private java.sql.Date birthDate;
    private List<Questions> userQuestions;
    private List<PostsComments> userPostsComments;
    private List<PostsInfo> userPosts;
    private List<Answer> answers;
    private UserImages userImage;
    private LogInfo logInfo;

    public UserInfo(){}

    public UserInfo(String email, String firstName, String lastName, java.sql.Date birthDate){
        this.email = email;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign",
    parameters = @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name = "property", value = "logInfo"))
    @Id @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    public long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "rating")
    public long getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "createDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @OrderColumn
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userInfo", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    public List<Questions> getUserQuestions() {
        return this.userQuestions;
    }

    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @OrderColumn
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userInfo", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    public List<PostsComments> getUserPostsComments() {
        return this.userPostsComments;
    }

    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @OrderColumn
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userInfo", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public List<PostsInfo> getUserPosts() {
        return this.userPosts;
    }

    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userInfo", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    public List<Answer> getAnswers() {
        return this.answers;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userInfo", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    public UserImages getUserImage() {
        return userImage;
    }

    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public LogInfo getLogInfo() {
        return logInfo;
    }

    @Column(name = "birthDate", nullable = false)
    public java.sql.Date getBirthDate() {
        return birthDate;
    }


 //Лишнее убрано
    }
```

К нему прилагается именованный запрос, который выбирает все значения в следующий DTO:

```
    public class CommonUserTransfer extends SmallUserTransfer{

    protected String lastName;
    protected java.util.Date createDate;
    protected java.util.Date birthDate;
    protected List<Questions> userQuestions;
    protected List<PostsComments> userPostsComments;
    protected List<PostsInfo> userPosts;
    protected List<Answer> answers;

    public CommonUserTransfer(long id, String firstName, byte[] userImage, long rating, String lastName,
                              java.util.Date createDate,
                              java.util.Date birthDate,
                              List<Questions> userQuestions,
                              List<PostsComments> postsComments,
                              List<PostsInfo> postsInfos,
                              List<Answer> answers) {
        super(id, firstName, userImage, rating);
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.createDate = createDate;
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
        this.userQuestions = userQuestions;
        this.userPostsComments = postsComments;
        this.userPosts = postsInfos;
        this.answers = answers;
    }
}
```

Дело в том, что при исполнении данного запроса Hibernate выдаёт SQL ошибку:

```
   ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as col_7_0_, . as col_8_0_, . as col_9_0_, . as col_10_0_ from userInfo userinfo' at line 1
```

Вот весь SQL, который он генерирует:

```
Hibernate: select userinfo0_.user_id as col_0_0_, userinfo0_.firstName as col_1_0_, userimages1_.image_l as col_2_0_, userinfo0_.rating as col_3_0_, userinfo0_.lastName as col_4_0_, userinfo0_.createDate as col_5_0_, userinfo0_.birthDate as col_6_0_, . as col_7_0_, . as col_8_0_, . as col_9_0_, . as col_10_0_ from userInfo userinfo0_ inner join userImages userimages1_ on userinfo0_.user_id=userimages1_.user_id inner join Questions userquesti2_ on userinfo0_.user_id=userquesti2_.user_id inner join postsComments userpostsc3_ on userinfo0_.user_id=userpostsc3_.user_id inner join postsInfo userposts4_ on userinfo0_.user_id=userposts4_.user_id inner join Answer answers5_ on userinfo0_.user_id=answers5_.user_id where userinfo0_.user_id=?
```

Т.е. в SQL все выборы коллекции замещены на `.` , как будто их нет, если я начинаю использовать тип `Collection<>` тогда мне выдаёт, что нельзя подгружать сразу несколько коллекций, поискал в гугле, написано что сразу несколько коллекций разрешено подгружать если использовать тип `List<>` и аннотацию `@OrderColumn` для данного листа

Читал документацию Hibernate, там довольно скудно рассказано об использовании DTO в `select`, не знаю что с этим делать, может кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

---

Что интересно при использовании следующего запроса:

```
 @NamedQuery(name = "getFullUser", query = "select u from UserInfo u " +
        " join fetch u.userImage " +
        " join fetch u.userQuestions " +
        " join fetch u.userPostsComments " +
        " join fetch u.userPosts  " +
        " join fetch u.answers  " +
        " where u.userId = :id")
```

запрос выполняется, но мне выдаёт ошибку, что такая сущность не найдена, хотя она есть в таблице. Если убрать `join fetch` коллекций(последние 4), то всё работает нормально. Может быть у меня с коллекциями что-то не так настроено?

Comment: За один запрос вы не получите объект сразу с 4 коллекциями (там где сказано что это можно, это ложь - т.к. противоречит логике реляционных баз данных). Разбейте запрос на 4 части: объект и первый лист, 3 листа отдельными запросами.

Comment: @АлександрСавостьянов На это есть Hibernate, который позволяет из одного запроса сделать несколько.

Comment: @RomanC, Я так понял, что кроме подзапросов для каждой коллекции по другом никак?

Comment: @ЕльцовДанил Я что-то не помню такого запроса, который возвращает коллекцию в множество результатов.

Comment: @RomanC, а вы не знаете случайно как устанавливаются теги для поста в ManyToMany ассоциацию, которые уже существуют, т.е. не делать же для каждого тега session.load() по id,

Comment: при обращении к тэгам загружается все, или же вы загружаете тэги вместе с вопросом, это зависит от стратегии загрузки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо нагромождать сложные запросы. Достаточно получить корневой объект, и не думать о зависимостях.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getCommonUser", query = "select u " +
            " from UserInfo as u " +
            " where u.userId = :id"),
```

Comment: Просто для получения отдельно всех элементов получается много запросов, разве это не нагружает бд?

Comment: `OneToMany`  отношения ленивые по умолчанию, и запросы появляются при обращении к коллекции, в этом случае выполняется  запрос связанный по внешнему ключу.

Comment: @RomanC, а можно ли как-то сделать отношение OneToOne ленивым, вроде написал fetch Lazy, optional false, а он все равно его тянет, вот хочу получить пост толькло с именем и тегами а он мне контент на 10000 слов подгружает

Comment: можно если соединить его по внешнему ключу и поставить unique

Comment: @RomanC, т.е. Добавить в таблицу родителя колонку - ссылку на вторую таблицу и через @JoinColumn?Прост они через первичный ключ соединены, видимо в этом проблема

Comment: Так можно только для этого придется писать ManyToOne а в реальности это будет один-к-одному отношение. То что касается OneToOne то вы перепутали главную и подчиненнную таблицы, на главной надо ставить `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userInfo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`, а на подчиненной `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`.

Comment: @RomanC, что интересно, именно так у меня и написано (плюс optional false) но он тянет за собой контент при обычной выборке сущности пост,  но все равно спасибо

Comment: `UserInfo` таблица является главной, а `LogInfo` - подчиненной, и уберите `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` c других полей.